Not able to access tenant.data in freemarker template
Following FusionAuth's documentation, I have set the following data using /api/tenant/${tenantId}
{
  "tenant" : {
    "data" : {
      "themes": {
         "portal_link" : "https://dev.example.com/assets"
      }
    }
  }
}

and I can see the tenant.data is getting set correctly

But, when I am trying to access the tenant.data.themes.portal_link in freemarker template e.g.
<p>${tenant.data.themes.portal_link}</p>

I am getting following error on oauthAuthorize page
Blamed expression: tenant.data.themes
Line number: 61
Column number: 24
End column number: 41
Theme Id: 1739e40b-1d70-4d8b-9704-292d5c46d22e
Template name: /oauth2/authorize.ftl

Message:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> tenant.data.themes


I was able to resolve this issue. I was testing with theme preview in fusion auth admin UI where it automatically selects the default tenant. While testing with actual app I was able to see the data set in non default tenant.
